# Tick label padding and tick label position on polar / radial chart - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to rotate the radial tick labels on the attached plot.

Why does matplotlib not rotate them when I have the 'rotation' command specified?

I would then like to shift the labels in the radial direction. Is there an equivalent of the 'pad' command with the polar charts?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

Graph_title = "Radar Plot"

def radarplot():
    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

    # INPUT DATA
    n_directions = 12
    angles = [n / float(n_directions) * 2 * math.pi for n in range(n_directions)]
    data = [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 2.75, 3.0, 3.0]

    # Add the last element of the list to the list. This is necessary or the line from 330 deg to 0 degree does not join up on the plot.
    angles = np.append(angles, angles[:1])
    data = np.append(data, data[:1])

    ax.plot(angles, data, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', color = 'red')

    # Radial tick parameters
    radial_ticks = [0.00, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00]
    ax.set_rlabel_position(45)
    ax.set_rorigin(0)
    plt.yticks(radial_ticks, color='black', size=8)
    ax.set_yticklabels(radial_ticks, rotation = 45, zorder = 500)

    # X Tick parameters
    plt.xticks(angles, color='black', size=10, zorder = 5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=3)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")         # Sets the labels initial position to 0 degrees
    ax.set_theta_direction("clockwise")     # Set the labels to rotate clockwise


    plt.savefig(Graph_title +".png", figsize = [6.4, 5], dpi=1000)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

radarplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem, and I only solved the rotation problem. `axis='x'` failed to control the rotation, only `axis='both'` can work.

```
ax.tick_params(
        axis='both',
        labelrotation=-45.,
        )
```

I am trying to solve the pad problem.

Comment: Please open a new question if you are trying to solve the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I wanted to achieve the same thing as you and here is the solution that I came up with.

1. Suppress the automatic r tick labels using the command `ax.set_yticklabels([])`
2. For each radial tick define a tick list, a position list, and an alignment list.
3. Using the `text` command write the values in the tick list at the radial locations specified by the position list with alignment specified by the alignment list.

Essentially the r ticks can be moved along the radial direction by changing the values in the position list.

Make sure that the `text` command is specified with `transform=ax.transData` option.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

Graph_title = "Radar Plot"

def radarplot():
    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

    # INPUT DATA
    n_directions = 12
    angles = [n / float(n_directions) * 2 * math.pi for n in range(n_directions)]
    data = [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 2.75, 3.0, 3.0]

    # Add the last element of the list to the list. This is necessary or the line from 330 deg to 0 degree does not join up on the plot.
    angles = np.append(angles, angles[:1])
    data = np.append(data, data[:1])

    ax.plot(angles, data, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', color = 'red')
    
    r_ticks = [0.00, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00] #tick list
    r_ticks_pos = [0.20, 0.65, 1.15, 1.65, 2.15, 2.65, 3.25] #radial position list (CHANGE THESE VALUES TO MOVE EACH TICK RADIALLY INDIVIDUALLY)
    r_ticks_h_align = ['center','center','center','center','center','center','center'] #horizontal alignment list
    r_ticks_v_align = ['center','center','center','center','center','center','center'] #vertical alignment list
    r_label_angle = 45 #theta angle

    # Radial tick parameters
    ax.set_rlabel_position(r_label_angle)
    ax.set_rorigin(0)
        
    ax.set_yticklabels([])    
    

    ax.set_rticks(r_ticks)
    ax.set_rlabel_position(r_label_angle)

    #write the ticks using the text command
    for rtick, rtick_pos, rtick_ha, rtick_va in zip(r_ticks, r_ticks_pos, r_ticks_h_align, r_ticks_v_align):
        plt.text(np.radians(r_label_angle), rtick_pos, r'$'+str(rtick)+'$', ha=rtick_ha, va=rtick_va, transform=ax.transData, rotation=-45, fontsize=8)

    # X Tick parameters
    plt.xticks(angles, color='black', size=10, zorder = 5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=3)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")         # Sets the labels initial position to 0 degrees
    ax.set_theta_direction("clockwise")     # Set the labels to rotate clockwise


    plt.savefig(Graph_title +".png", figsize = [6.4, 5], dpi=1000)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

radarplot()
```

And the result:

[image]